# AngularJS Routing for HTML pages inside slideshow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an idea for a website I am building, I wanted it to be a slideshow with a nav bar at the top that when you click, it will flip through the slideshow to that "slide" or category. I wanted each slide to be its own html page that I could uniquely customize... But now I am having a hard time actually putting these HTML pages into a slideshow.

I was thinking AngularJS routing might be the way to go? But I want it to be an actual slideshow/carousel that the user can flick through instead of being reliant on the nav bar.

So my main question is: will AngularJS routing be the best way to achieve this? If so how might I use the routing in say, a slick carousel? Otherwise, what might be people's thoughts on how to achieve this?

Thank you for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only use the routing feature to create a deep-linking functionality, whereby the user can be taken to a specific slide based on the address bar, or vice-versa the address hash changing when the carousel 'slides'.
As far as routing beyond the hash, you wouldn't want to trigger a page change as this may force your carousel to reload.

Another note: Angular-JS routing doesn't support nested views, such as UI-Router does. You may want to utilize nested views for your 'carousel slides'

Comment: Ok thank you. Are you suggesting that I should leave navigation solely to the address bar and not let the user manually slide through?

Comment: If that is possible, but if not, ui-router can let you access each different slide as a view and switch views using the routing events on the address bar.